# Magento url_key for products does not work. Magento adds an increasing ID for each update,

Tags: magento

during importing products to magento I use `setUrlKey` method for setting the `url_key` property:

```
$products_name = "I am a test product";
$product->setUrlKey($products_name);
```

This works fine, but when I open the product in the shop the `url` is not

`"i-am-a-test-product"`. The `url` is `"i-am-a-test-product-1"`. When I restart my import script the url will be "i-am-a-test-product-2". Magento adds an ID after the `url_key` and increases it for each run.

Of the course all products names are unique.

How can I stop `magento` adding these ID's inside the `url_key`?

For categories I do not have these problems.

Comment: By the way. Inside the magento Admin the urlkey is correct! But inside the catalog magento uses the urlkey with appending id.

Comment: I have looked into the catalog_product_entity_varchar table. There the url_key (attribute 97) is right. The wrong url is listed under attribute 98 which is named urlpath. Maybe somebody has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your own url key by this code:

```
$urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $products_name);
$urlKey = strtolower($urlKey);
$product->setUrlKey($urlKey);
```

Or you can use this method from catalog product model

```
$urlKey = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->formatUrlKey($products_name);
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work when I add an urlkey on this way. I used your function for this test purpose. Mangento still adds its own id after urlkey.

Comment: Look into URL Rewrite Management and check whether there are paths for this product, if paths exist remove all, remove this product and try to import again